# Obtener el nombre de las columnas de un dataSet

Tags: c#

Buenas resulta que tengo un método que me devuelve un DataSet con los datos de una consulta SQL, lo que quiero es obtener el NOMBRE de esas columnas 
ejemplo del método

```
List<string> nombreColumnas;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = _Conector.ejecutarConsulta(sNombrePaquete, "PRSTARM_CUENTA", "RESULTADO", true);
```

quiero llenar la lista con el nombre de esas columnas

Agradezco de antemano cualquier tipo de ayuda

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El `DataTable` tien una propiedad `Columns` para obtener esa informacion

[DataTable.Columns Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columns?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
List<string> nombreColumnas = new List<string>();

foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
   nombreColumnas.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
```

Si vas a trabjar con una sola tabla no uses un DataSet, usa un DataTable